# browserify cannot find global npm modules

Tags: node.js, browserify

Note: I don't know anything about the js world, so assume nothing.

I am trying to get a basic tutorial started. I installed npm and browserify installed, then I installed the uniq package with

```
npm install -g uniq
```

When I try to create the browserify bundle I get this message:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'uniq' from '/Users/.../static/js'
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:46:17
    at process (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:173:43)
    at ondir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:188:17)
    at load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)
    at onex (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:22:47
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
```

If I remove the -g when installing uniq it works, but I can't understand why it's not working when using the global dir. I also checked under /usr/local/lib and there's a node_modules dir that does contain a uniq directory.

Comment: Avoid installing global modules unless you want a utility on local system, use `package.json` for portable projects . The particular error seems to be from [`resolve`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve) module. Perhaps browserify is using it to resolve module path, but is looking in `'/Users/.../static/js'` ?

Comment: @S.D.: I spent a few hours on it, and found out that apparently it was an interaction between the `require` from node.js and the `require` from requirejs.